# Declaring object type via String

Tags: java, mysql, string, jdbc

Here is my function:

```
private boolean CheckPassword(String type, String login, String passwordHash) {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory 
            = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("kwestionariuszFor" + type);
    EntityManager entityManager 
            = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    type = type.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + type.substring(1, type.length());
    List<Object> entities 
            = entityManager.createNamedQuery(type + ".findByLogin").setParameter("login", login).getResultList();
    if (passwordHash.equals(entities.get(0).Password)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The Java doesn't "know" that there IS Password column in any of the tables. I was thinking that the way to tell it so may look like this:

```
List<type.toClass()>
```

or something... is there any way to achieve what I want? I don't want to create if, after if, after if... -_-'

Comment: Looks like you are trying to cast. How will you know if the type you are recieving has a password field at all?

Comment: "Stringly typed code" =(

Comment: @Emily, because this function is called only from within four other functions that can be cast only on objects having password fields. :)

Comment: @LouisWasserman, what is wrong with it, exactly? I mean, the alternative would take self-repeating and loops in loops... there should be pre-build functions like String.toClass, String.toVariableName, etc. ;-)

Comment: Even that solution uses too many `String`s.  The preferred solutions is to refer to types by more complex objects: for example, instead of taking a `String type` argument in the `CheckPassword` method, you should pass in a generic object that knows the names of all the queries.  For example, instead of a `"foo"` "string type," create something like an `EntityManagerType<T>` class with a `queryName()` method, and have an `EntityManagerType<Foo>` that knows everything about the `Foo` type.  (Without knowing more details about the context, I can't suggest more appropriate names or the like.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman, yeah, did it, good idea, thanks. I'm a beginner. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a common type for all of your classes that represent database tables.

Like this:

```
public abstract class PasswordObject {
    private String password;

    public PasswordObject(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

I don't know if the method `createNamedQuery` would be able to return a `List<PassowrdObject>`, but if not, you can just cast it like this (as long as it's safe to do so, which you can only tell by the way you use it):

```
PasswordObject po = (PasswordObject) entities.get(0);
String password = po.getPassword();
```

Comment: Well, I thought this will work but I've got "can't cast" error so I get and idea to recreate the mysql query... not everything have to be done with Java, right? ;-)

Comment: I don't know which framework you're using, but there must be a way to get a List<A> where A is the type you want! You probably get a List<Object> because you're misusing the framework, this is not good practice. In Spring JDBC, you would have an ObjectMapper which maps your DB table to a Java Object, so you do something like: List<A> result = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new A_Mapper() );